# image is reset when I edit (update) a post in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I can create a post. Also, it is available to add image in the post. But when I edit post later, the image is removed and I have to add this image again in each editing. How can I do that the image will be remembered for always and it will be changed only in case if i will be add new?

AdminController.cs (it's responsible for editing)

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult EditPost(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return View(new PostViewModel());
            }
            else
            {
                var post = _repo.GetPost((int)id);
                return View(new PostViewModel
                {
                    Id = post.Id,
                    Text = post.Text,
                });
            }
        }

[HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(PostViewModel vm)
      {
         var post = new Post
         {
            Id = vm.Id,
            Text = vm.Text,
            Image = await _fileManager.SaveImage(vm.Image)
         };
         if (post.Id == 0)
            _repo.AddPost(post);
         else
            _repo.UpdatePost(post);
         if (await _repo.SaveChangesAsync())
            return RedirectToAction("Posts");
         else
            return View(post);
      }
```

Post.cs in Models

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; } = "";
        public string Image { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
```

Repository.cs

```
public void UpdatePost(Post post)
        {
            _ctx.Post.Update(post);
        }
```

IRepository.cs

```
void UpdatePost(Post post);
```

Just in case I publish PostController.cs

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var posts = _repo.GetAllPosts();
            return View(posts);
        }

        public IActionResult Post(int id)
        {
            var post= _repo.GetPost(id);
            return View(post);
        }

        [HttpGet("/Image/{image}")]

        public IActionResult Image(string image)
        {
            var path = image.Substring(image.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            return new FileStreamResult(_fileManager.ImageStream(image), $"image/{path}");
        }
```

Comment: WIll you include your edit view?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow many diffirent approach for that but i will refer two of them. First, you can carry image to client-side, then again, carry it to backend. You should send the image to backend as well.

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult EditPost(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return View(new PostViewModel());
        }
        else
        {
            var post = _repo.GetPost((int)id);
            return View(new PostViewModel
            {
                Id = post.Id,
                Text = post.Text,
                Image = post.Image
            });
        }
    }
```

And second, you can only update image when imageUrl is not empty. But this will come with a new condition, "what if client wants to delete the image?". You should decide when you are sure what exactly want to do. I'm adding some uncompleted code just to give some idea.

```
 [HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(PostViewModel vm)
{
  var post = new Post
  {
    Id = vm.Id,
    Text = vm.Text,
    Image = await _fileManager.SaveImage(vm.Image)
  };


  if (post.Id == 0)
    _repo.AddPost(post);
  else
  {
    if (vm.Image == null)
    {
      //Overwriting viewmodel's image property if empty with old record's image.
      var oldRecord = _repo.GetPost(vm.Id);
      post.Image = oldRecord?.Image;
    }
    _repo.UpdatePost(post);
  }

  if (await _repo.SaveChangesAsync())
    return RedirectToAction("Posts");
  else
    return View(post);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for feedback. Unfortunately, there is an error in second option: CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile' to 'string'

Comment: Sorry. I didnot test it and now it shoul work. It seems your Image property of PostViewModel is type of Image

Comment: in PostViewModel there is `public IFormFile Image { get; set; } = null;`

Comment: Ok then. I have edited my response. Can you try it again?

Comment: There are no errors in Visual Studio log, however, it doesn't work. When I edit post, there is shown that "image file is not chosen". When I update post, there is an error:
The instance of entity type 'Post' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
Only if I choose again some image it will update sucessfully.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. The file upload cannot be set by the server, because the server does not have access to the client's filesystem. The client must *always* consent to uploading a local file, and that consent is given via the file upload dialog. If the client is sent back to the form due to a validation error, they must upload the file again.

Now, that said, there's workarounds, though none of them ideal. The file input can be manually set with file *data* (just not a filesystem reference) via the JavaScript File API. You could use the File API to read the file data after the user chooses a file, store that in localStorage (in the browser) and then attempt to read from localStorage on page load, and set the file input to that file data, if there's a key present.

However, localStorage has a hard limit of 10MB total, so you'd need to be careful to ensure that the file size does not exceed that, along with anything else that might already be stored or will be stored there, as well.

Alternatively, you can store the file server-side before you send the user back, so that it's still available after they correct their entries and re-post. However, the user may abandon the form entirely or upload a new file instead, so you'd need a strategy for cleaning up these temporary files.